# webview not working properly after enabling proguard

Tags: android, android-webview, proguard

webview is not working properly with proguard in signed apk, but works in debug apk.

I added exclusion for javascriptInterface in proguard rules, but its not working for release build.

```
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class * {
@android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

and in my build gradle

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }

        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I am setting "minifyEnabled true" for both debug and release, but the exception added in proguard rules working only for debug.
All suggestions appreciated.